# How to vary the length of a combination of bounds based on the length of an array

Tags: arrays, vba, string

I have this script in VBA and I need to apply it to different paths that I need to split. Each path is different in length and has several slash delimiters (`/`) separating it.

If I exceed the number of elements in the array in the `LBound` function, an error is returned to me.

**Question**

How do I dynamically combine this pattern based on length.

**Example with 3 elements**

That is, if I have an initial array of this type

- `"category / subcategory / product"`

I have to get

- `"category; category> subcategory; category> subcategory> product"`

I have many paths of this type, but sometimes they are composed of 3 parts, other times 4, 5 or even more. This is my starting VBA.

```vb
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strFolderString As String
    Dim arrFolderString As Variant
    Dim result As String
    Dim lenght As Integer

    strFolderString = "category\subcategory\product\CustomerName\ProductName\2017\"
    arrFolderString = Split(strFolderString, "\")
    lenght = UBound(arrFolderString)
    result = _
        arrFolderString(LBound(arrFolderString) + 1) & ";" & _
        arrFolderString(LBound(arrFolderString) + 1) & " > " & _
        arrFolderString(LBound(arrFolderString) + 2) & ";" & _
        arrFolderString(LBound(arrFolderString) + 1) & " > " & _
        arrFolderString(LBound(arrFolderString) + 2) & " > " & _
        arrFolderString(LBound(arrFolderString) + 3)
    Debug.Print result
End Sub
```

Comment: one note: Split always returns a 0 based array.  so `LBound(arrFolderString)` will always be `0`.  No need to add it to set numbers.  Just use the numbers: `result = arrFolderString(1) & ";" & arrFolderString(1) & " > " & arrFolderString(2) & ";" & arrFolderString(1) & " > " & arrFolderString(2) & " > " & arrFolderString(3)`

Comment: and I think you actually want: `result = arrFolderString(0) & ";" & arrFolderString(0) & " > " & arrFolderString(1) & ";" & arrFolderString(0) & " > " & arrFolderString(1) & " > " & arrFolderString(2)`

Comment: yes that's ok but I don't Know how much numeber... I need to make this growing chain without knowing the number for position in the array. How I make that?

Comment: There has to be a rule, If the items can be anywhere in the string you will not be able to program it.  VBA does not know what could be a category a  sub category etc.  If it is always the first three then that should work.  Otherwise, there probably is no way to do this.

Comment: the order is always the same. the problem is that one time I can have array dimension 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 So for example one time category\subcategory\product\ another time category\subcategory\product\CustomerName another one category\subcategory\product\CustomerName\ProductName\2017\ and so on. Obviously I'll made a cicle for for it, but inside the cicle i need that changing on the array lenght base.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following approach to get the dynamic path infos by a tricky loop restricting the inner loop to the current outer value:

```
Sub PathInfo()
'1) define path input
    Dim strFolderString As String
    strFolderString = _
    "category\subcategory\product\CustomerName\ProductName\2017\"
    'remove end slash
    strFolderString = Replace(strFolderString & "\", "\\", "")
'2) split parts into array
    Dim arrFolderString As Variant
    arrFolderString = Split(strFolderString, "\")
'3) Provide for sufficient elements in results array
    Dim lastIndex As Long: lastIndex = UBound(arrFolderString)
    Dim results(): ReDim results(0 To lastIndex)
'4) Join Path infos
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 0 To lastIndex
        Dim delim As String: delim = ""
        For j = 0 To i                       ' << restrict inner loop to i :-)
            Dim tmp As String
            results(i) = tmp & delim & arrFolderString(j)
            delim = ">"
        Next j
        tmp = results(i)
    Next
'5) Show Result
    Debug.Print Join(results, ";" & vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

**Results in VB Editors immediate window**

```
category;
category>subcategory;
category>subcategory>product;
category>subcategory>product>CustomerName;
category>subcategory>product>CustomerName>ProductName;
category>subcategory>product>CustomerName>ProductName>2017
```